# Our Reading List

Tags: discussion

I commence a Reading List, ordered by ascending year, based on [r/linguistics's wiki](https://old.reddit.com/r/linguistics/wiki/readinglist#wiki_semantics). But I added  books not there, and updated many edition numbers and publication years. That Wiki hasn't been updated since 2006. If I get time, I'll update all the edition numbers and publication years.

Then we won't need to be flooded with [this kind of question](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1990). We can simply refer tyros to our Reading List. The other advantages are self explanatory.

Does anyone know how to simultaneously

1. convert all the bullet points to numbers? Undoubtedly, it's too unproductive to delete each `-` and add a number singly.
2. sort the list by the four-digit year? It's too inefficient to re-order all the books individually.

---

## [Introductions](http://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/wiki/generalreading)

- Mark Aronoff, Janie Rees-Miller. *The Handbook of Linguistics*. (2003).

1. P. H. Matthews. *Linguistics: A Very Short Introduction* (2003).

- Kate Burridge, Tonya Stebbins. *For the Love of Language: An Introduction to Linguistics*. (2015).
- David Crystal. *How language works*. (2006).
- Bruce Hayes - *Introductory Linguistics*. (2010).
- Ray Jackendoff. *Foundations of Language: Brain, Meaning, Grammar, Evolution*. (2003).
- Andrew Radford, Martin Atkinson, David Britain, Harald Clahsen, Andrew Spencer. *Linguistics: An Introduction*. (2009).
- Ohio State University Press. *Language Files 11: Materials for an Introduction to Language and Linguistics*. (2011).

1. Stephen Anderson. *Languages: A Very Short Introduction* (2012).
2. Ian Roberts. *The Wonders of Language* (2017).
3. Adrian Akmajian, Richard A. Demers, Ann K. Farmer, and Robert M. Harnish. Linguistics: *An Introduction to Language and Communication*. (2017 7 ed).
4. Victoria Fromkin, Robert Rodman, Nina M. Hyams. *An Introduction to Language*. (2018 11 ed).
5. George Yule. *The Study of Language*. (2019 7 ed).

## [Phonetics](http://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/wiki/phoneticsreading)

1. J. C. Catford. *A Practical Introduction to Phonetics*. (2003 2 ed.)

- Mike Davenport, S. J. Hannahs. *Introducing Phonetics and Phonology*. (2005).
- Peter Ladefoged, Keith Johnson. *A Course in Phonetics*. (2011).
- Richard Ogden. *An Introduction to English Phonetics*. (2009).

#### Acoustic/Auditory Phonetics

- Keith Johnson. *Acoustic and Auditory Phonetics*. (2003).
- Kenneth N Stevens. *Acoustic Phonetics*. (2000).

#### Articulatory Phonetics

- Anita C. Bickford, Rick Floyd. *Articulatory Phonetics: Tools for Analyzing the World's Languages*. (2006).
- Alain Marchal. *From Speech Physiology to Linguistic Phonetics*. (2009).

### [Phonology](http://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/wiki/phonologyreading)

- Philip Carr. *Phonology*. (1993).
- Bruce Hayes. *Introductory Phonology*. (2009).
- John Jensen. *Principles of Generative Phonology*. (2004).

1. John Clark, Colin Yallop. *An Introduction to Phonetics and Phonology* (Blackwell textbook series, 2006).

- Paul de Lacy. *The Cambridge Handbook of Phonology*. (2007).
- David Odden - *Introducing Phonology*. (2005).

2. Charles Reiss and Alan Bale. *Phonology: A formal introduction* (2018).

#### Derivational Phonology

- Michael Kenstowicz. *Phonology in Generative Grammar*. (1994)

#### Autosegmental Theory

#### Optimality Theory

- René Kager. *Optimality Theory*. (2004).
- John J. McCarthy. *A Thematic Guide to Optimality Theory* (2002).
- John J. McCarthy. *Optimality Theory in Phonology: A Reader* (2004).

## [Morphology](http://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/wiki/morphologyreading)

- Mark Aronoff, Kirsten Fudeman. *What is Morphology?*. (2011).
- Geert Booij. *The Grammar of Words: An Introduction to Linguistic Morphology*. (2011).
- Martin Haspelmath, Andrea D. Sims. *Understanding Morphology*. (2010).
- Rochelle Lieber. *Introducing Morphology*. (2009).
- Thomas E. Payne. *Describing Morphosyntax: A Guide For Field Linguists*. (1997)

## [Syntax](http://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/wiki/syntaxreading)

- Paul R. Kroeger. *Analyzing Grammar: An Introduction*. (2005).
- T. Givón. *Syntax: An Introduction*. 2 vols. (2001)
- Andrew Radford. *Minimalist Syntax Revisited*. (2006).

1. [See this question contrasting Andrew Radford's sundry textbooks on syntax](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/36337).

- Robert D. Van Valin, Jr. *An Introduction to Syntax*. (2004).

2. Maggie Tallerman. *Understanding Syntax*. (2020 5 ed).
3. Andrew Carnie. *Syntax: A Generative Introduction*. (2021 4 ed).

## [Semantics and Pragmatics](http://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/wiki/semanticspragmaticsreading)

- K. M. Jaszczolt. *Semantics and Pragmatics*. (2002).

2. Alan Cruse. *Meaning in Language: An Introduction to Semantic and Pragmatics*. (2011 3 ed).

## [Semantics](http://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/wiki/semanticsreading)

- Claudia Maienborn, Klaus von Heusinger, Paul Portner. *Semantics: An International Handbook of Natural Language Meaning*. (2011).
- Nick Riemer. *Introducing Semantics*. (2010).

1. Kate Kearns. *Semantics*. (2011 2 ed).
2. Sebastian Löbner. *Understanding Semantics*. (2013 2 ed).

#### Lexical Semantics

- Dirk Geeraerts. *Theories of Lexical Semantics*

#### Formal Semantics

- Chris Fox, Shallom Lappin. *Foundations of Intensional Semantics*. (2005).
- Irene Heim & Angleika Kratzer. *Semantics in Generative Grammar*. (1998).
- Paul Portner. *What is Meaning? Fundamentals of Formal Semantics*. (2005).
- Paul Portner, Barbara H. Partee. *Formal Semantics: The Essential Readings*. (2002).
- Henriëtte de Swart. *Introduction to Natural Language Semantics*. (1998).

#### Cognitive Semantics

- Jens Allwood, Peter Gärdenfors. *Cognitive Semantics: Meaning and Cognition*. (1999).

## [Pragmatics](http://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/wiki/pragmaticsreading)

1. J.L. Austin. *How to Do Things with Words (William James Lectures)* (1962, ed. J. O. Urmson and Marina Sbisà)
2. George Yule. *Pragmatics* (1996).

- Betty J. Birner. *Introduction to Pragmatics*. (2011).
- Joan Cutting. *Pragmatics and Discourse: A Resource Book for Students*. (2002).
- Yan Huang. *Pragmatics*. (2007).
- Jacob May. *Pragmatics: An Introduction*. (2001).
- Stephen Levinson. *Pragmatics*. (1983).

## [Historical and Comparative Linguistics](http://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/wiki/historicalcomparativereading)

- Hans Henrich Hock. *Principles of Historical Linguistics*. (1991).
- Hans Henrich Hock, Brian D. Joseph. *Language History, Language Change, and Language Relationship: An Introduction to Historical and Comparative Linguistics*. (1996).

1. Terry Crowley and Claire Bowern. *An Introduction to Historical Linguistics*, (2010 4 ed).

- Lyle Campbell. *Historical Linguistics: An Introduction.* (2013).
- Larry Trask & Robert McColl Millar. *Trask's Historical Linguistics.* (2015 3 ed).

## [Language Acquisition](http://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/wiki/languageacquisitionreading)

- Maria Teresa Guasti. *Language Acquisition: The Growth of Grammar*. (2002).
- Jill de Villiers, Tom Roeper. *Handbook of Generative Approaches to Language Acquisition*. (2011).

### L1 Acquisition

1. Eve Clark. *First Language Acquisition*. (2003).
2. Charles Yang. *The Infinite Gift: How Children Learn and Unlearn the Languages of the World* (2006).

### L2 Acquisition

1. Kristen  Hummel. *Introducing second language acquisition : perspectives and practices*.
2. Muriel Saville-Troike. *Introducing second language acquisition*.
3. Lourdes Ortega. *Understanding second language acquisition*.
4. Jennifer Larson-Hall. *Second language acquisition myths : applying second language research to classroom teaching* (2012).
5. Patsy Lightbown. *How Languages are Learned*  (2013 4 ed).
6. Rosamund Mitchell. *Second language learning theories* (2013).
7. David Michael Singleton. *Key topics in second language acquisition* (2014).
8. Rod Ellis. *Understanding second language acquisition* (2015 2 ed).
9. Vivian Cook. *Second Language Learning and Language Teaching* (2016 5 ed).
10. Roumyana Slabakova.  *Second language acquisition* (2016)
11. Theodore Rogers. *Approaches and Methods in Language Teaching* (Cambridge Language Teaching Library) (2017 3 ed).

## [Sociolinguistics](http://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/wiki/sociolinguisticsreading)

- J. K. Chambers. *Sociolinguistic Theory: Revised Edition*. (2008).

1. John Edwards. *Sociolinguistics: A Very Short Introduction* (2013).

- Janet Holmes. *An introduction to sociolinguistics*. (2008).
- Miriam Meyerhoff. *Introducing Sociolinguistics*. (2006).
- Sali A. Tagliamonte. *Analysing Sociolinguistic Variation*. (2006).
- Suzanne Romaine. *Language in Society: An Introduction to Sociolinguistics*. (2000).
- Ronald Wardhaugh. *An Introduction to Sociolinguistics*. (2009).

## [Psycholinguistics](http://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/wiki/psycholinguisticsreading)

- Trevor A. Harley. *Talking the talk.* (2010).

## [Cognitive Linguistics](http://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/wiki/cognitivesreading)

- Eugene H. Casad, Gary B. Palmer. *Cognitive Linguistics and Non-Indo-European Languages*. (2003).
- William Croft, D. Allan Cruse. *Cognitive Linguistics*. (2004).
- Vyvyan Evans, Melanie Green. *Cognitive Linguistics: An Introduction*. (2006).
- Dirk Geeraerts, Hubert Cuyckens. *The Oxford Handbook of Cognitive Linguistics*. (2007).
- Gitte Kristiansen, Michel Achard, René Dirven, Francisco J.Ruiz de Mendoza Ibáñez. *Cognitive Linguistics: Current Applications and Future Perspectives*. (2006).
- Francisco J. Ruiz de Mendoza Ibáñez, M. Sandra Peña Cervel. *Cognitive Linguistics: Internal Dynamics and Interdisciplinary Interaction*. (2005).
- Stephen Levinson. *Space in Language and Cognition: Explorations in cognitive diversity*. (2003).

## [Descriptive Linguistics](http://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/wiki/descriptivereading)

- T. Givón. *Syntax: An Introduction*. 2 vols. (2001).
- Thomas E. Payne. *Describing Morphosyntax: A Guide For Field Linguists*. (1997).
- Claire Bowern. *Linguistics Fieldwork: A practical guide.* (2008).
- Timothy Shopen (ed). *Language Typology and Syntactic Description.* Vol I-III. (2007).
- RMW Dixon. *Basic Linguistic Theory*. Vol I-III. (2009).

## [Corpus Linguistics](http://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/wiki/corpusreading)

- Stefan Th. Gries. *Quantitative Corpus Linguistics with R: A Practical Introduction*. (2009).
- Tony McEnery, Andrew Hardie. *Corpus linguistics: method, theory and practice*. (2012).
- Tony McEnery, Richard Xiao, Yukio Tono. *Corpus-Based Language Studies: an advanced resource book*. (2006)

## Books on each Language Family

#### Afro-Asiatic

#### Australian

- Blake, Barry. Australian Aboriginal Grammar (RLE Linguistics F: World Linguistics). Routledge, 2014.
- Dixon, Robert Malcolm Ward. The languages of Australia. Cambridge University Press, 2011.
- Koch, Harold, and Rachel Nordlinger, eds. The languages and linguistics of Australia: A comprehensive guide. Vol. 3. Walter de Gruyter GmbH & Co KG, 2014.
- Evans, Nick, ed. The non-Pama-Nyungan languages of northern Australia: comparative studies of the continent's most linguistically complex region. Pacific Linguistics, 2003.
- S. A. Wurm. *Languages of Australia and Tasmania*. (1972).

#### Austronesian

- Peter Bellwood, James Fox, Darrell Tryon (eds.). [*The Austronesians: Historical and Comparative Perspectives*](http://epress.anu.edu.au/austronesians/austronesians/pdf/austronesians-whole.pdf). (2006).
- Robert Blust. [*The Austronesian Languages*](https://digitalcollections.anu.edu.au/bitstream/1885/10191/1/Blust_AustronesianLanguages2013.pdf). (2009).
- John Lynch, Malcolm Ross, Terry Crowley (eds.). *The Oceanic Languages*. (2002).
- Malcolm Ross. *Proto Oceanic and the Austronesian languages of Western Melanesia*. (1988).
- Malcolm Ross, Andrew Pawley, Meredith Osmond (eds.). *The Lexicon of Proto Oceanic*. Vol 1: (1998), [Vol 2: (2003)](http://epress.anu.edu.au/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/whole-book.pdf), Vol 3: (2008), Vol 4: (2011), Vol 5,6,7 (forthcoming).
- Alexander Adelaar, Nikolaus P. Himmelmann (eds.). *The Austronesian Languages of Asia and Madagascar*. (2005).
- [/r/Austronesian](https://old.reddit.com/r/Austronesian)

#### Basque

- Ander Egurtzegi. *Phonetics and Phonology*. (2013).
- José Ignacio Hualde, Ortiz de Urbina (eds.). *A Grammar of Basque*. (2003).
- Alan R. King. *The Basque Language: A Practical Introduction*. (1994).
- Joseba Lakarra. *Notas sobre iniciales, cambio tipologicio, y prehistoria del verbo vasco*. (2006).
- Rudolph P. G. de Rijk. *Standard Basque: A Progressive Grammar*. (2007).
- R. L. Trask. *The History of Basque*. (1996).
- R. L. Trask. *Etymological Dictionary of Basque*. Ed. by Max Wheeler. (2008).

#### Cariban

#### Finno-Ugric

- Péter Hajdú (transl. and adapted by G. F. Cushing). *Finno-Ugrian Languages and Peoples*. (1975).
- Angela Marcantonio. *The Uralic Language Family. Facts, Myths and Statistics*. (2002).

#### Indo-European

- Robert S. P. Beekes. *Comparative Indo-European Linguistics: An Introduction*. 2nd Edition. (2011).
- Benjamin W. Fortson IV. *Indo-European Language and Culture: An Introduction*. (2004).
- J. P. Mallory, D. Q. Adams. *The Oxford Introduction to Proto-Indo-European and the Proto-Indo-European World*. (2006).
- Ranko Matasovic. *A Reader in Comparative Indo-European Religion*. (2010).
- Don Ringe. "Proto-Indo-European" in *From Proto-Indo-European to Proto-Germanic*. (2006).
- Calvert Watkins. *How to Kill a Dragon: Aspects of Indo-European Poetics*. (2001).

#### Japonic

- Bjarke Frellesvig. *A History of the Japanese Language*. (2010).
- Miyake, Marc Hideo. Old Japanese: A phonetic reconstruction. Routledge, 2013.
- Pellard, Thomas. "Ryukyuan and the reconstruction of proto-Japanese-Ryukyuan." Handbook of Japanese historical linguistics. Berlin: De Gruyter Mouton (2018).
- Roy Andrew Miller. *Origins of the Japanese Language*. (1980).

#### Kartvelian

- Winfried Boeder. *The South Caucasian Languages*. (2003/2004).
- Georgiĭ Andreevich Klimov. *Etymological Dictionary of the Kartvelian Languages*. 1998.
- Heinz Fähnrich. *Kartwelisches Etymologisches Wörterbuch*. (2007).

#### Koreanic

- Sohn, Ho-min. Chapters 3 & 4 of *The Korean Language*. (1999).
- Lee, Iksop, and S. Robert Ramsey. The Korean Language. Suny Press, 2001.
- Brown, Lucien, and Jaehoon Yeon, eds. The handbook of Korean linguistics. John Wiley & Sons, 2015.
- Lee, EunHee, Sean Madigan, and Mee-Jeong Park. An introduction to Korean linguistics. Routledge, 2015.

#### Niger-Congo

#### Northeast Caucasian (Nakho-Dagestanian)

- Keith Plaster, Maria Polinsky, Boris Harizanov. *Noun Classes Grow on Trees: Noun Classification in North-East Caucasian*. (2012).

#### Northwest Caucasian (Abkhazo-Adyghean)

- Ranko Matasovic. *A Short Grammar of East Circassian (Kabardian).* Translated by Tenja Gnjatovic. Version 9. (2010).
- Aert H. Kuipers. *Phoneme and morpheme in Kabardian (Eastern Adyghe)*. (1960).

#### Papuan

- Andrew Pawley, Robert Attenborough, Jack Golson, Robin Hide (eds.). *Papuan Pasts: Cultural, linguistic and biological histories of Papuan-speaking peoples*. (2005).
- William Foley. *The Papuan languages of New Guinea*. (1986).

#### Pre-Greek

- Robert S. P. Beekes. *Pre-Greek. A Language Reconstructed.* Version 2. (2003).
- Robert S. P. Beekes. Introduction in *Etymological Dictionary of Greek*. (2009).
- Robert S. P. Beekes, ed. Stefan Norbruis. *Pre-Greek: Phonology, Morphology, Lexicon*.  (2014).
- Yves Duhoux. *Pre-Hellenic Language(s) of Crete*. (1998).

#### Sino-Tibetan

a.k.a. Tibeto-Burman, a.k.a. Trans-Himalayan

- LaPolla, Randy J., and Graham Thurgood. The Sino-Tibetan Languages. Routledge, 2016.
- Kane, Daniel. *The Chinese Language: Its History and Current Usage*. (2006)
- Norman, Jerry. *Chinese*. (1988).
- Benedict, Paul K. *Sino-Tibetan: A Conspectus*. (1972)
- Van Driem, George. "Trans-Himalayan." In Trans-Himalayan Linguistics, pp. 11-40. De Gruyter Mouton, 2013.
- LaPolla, Randy. "Subgrouping in Tibeto-Burman." Language typology and historical contingency (2013): 463-474.

#### Turkic

- Csató, Éva Ágnes, Lars Johanson. *The Turkic Languages*. Routledge, (1998).

#### Tyrrhenian

- Robert S. P. Beekes. *The Origin of the Etruscans*. (2003).
- Bonfante Giuliano, Bonfante Larissa. *The Etruscan Language. An Introduction*. 2nd ed. (2002).
- Rex E. Wallace. Zikh Rasna: *A Manual of the Etruscan Language and Inscriptions*. (2008).

#### Uto-Aztecan

Comment: What is the question? A list of references is not a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you paste your list as is into a .doc file, then ask .xls to convert the .doc into a table using for example <.> as column boundary, you'll get a table with the author, the title and the year in separate columns.
Afterwards you can reorganize the data as you'd like to.